# Use of open interval in proof of Squeeze Rule for continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I have a question with regards to the use of an open interval in the following theorem:

> **Theorem:**
>
> Let $f, g, h$ be defined on an open interval $I$ and let $a \in I$. If
>
> 1. $g(x) \le f(x) \le h(x)$ for $x \in I$,
> 2. $g(a) = f(a) = h(a)$
> 3. $g, h$ are continuous at $a$
>
> ... then $f$ is also continuous at $a$.
>
> **Proof:**
>
> - We want to show that for each sequence $(x_n)$ in the domain of $f$ such that $x_n \rightarrow a$, we have $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(a)$.
> - Since $x_n \rightarrow a$ and $I$ is an open interval, there is an integer $N$ such that $x_n \in I$, for $n > N$.
>   Hence by condition 1., $g(x_n) \le f(x_n) \le h(x_n)$ for $n > N$.
>
> ...
>
> [ Rest of the proof omitted. ]

I understand the rest of the proof, which is basically an application of the Squeeze Theorem of convergent sequences.

- I was wondering why we use an *open* interval $I$?
- Also, I understand that we pick a sequence $(x_n)$ from the domain of $f$ which tends to $a$. To use this sequence, we also need to make sure the sequence is included in $I$. In the proof they say:

> - *Since $x_n \rightarrow a$ and $I$ is an open interval*, there is an integer $N$ such that $x_n \in I$, for $n > N$.

I get that we show eventually $(x_n)$ will be in $I$, but how is this justified by $I$ being an open interval?

- Lastly, can we always make sure to find a sequence $(x_n)$ in the domain of $f$ which has limit $a$ and fits into an open interval?

Comment: I believe it's because, since $I$ is open, there is a neighborhood $V(a)\subset I$ of $a$ that is contained entirely in $I$. Therefore, any sequence that converges to $a$ must be contained in $I$ eventually. Why the proof can't work if $a$ is a boundary point of a closed interval, I'm not positive. It seems that the assumption of $(x_n)\subset I$ being a sequence of elements of the domain should be sufficient.

Comment: @c_gnar - It is poorly worded, but I believe that they do not mean that $g, f, h$ have domains limited to the interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theorem works because $g \le f \le h$ is true for all points in some neighborhood of $a$ (a set of points that includes everything close to $a$ for some level of closeness). On the real line, any neighborhood of a point contains on open interval around that point. Thus the theorem works because $g \le f \le h$ on some open interval containing $a$.

This is not true for closed intervals containing $a$, since then $a$ could be an end point of the interval, and we are not guaranteed that $g\le f\le h$ on the other side. For example $$g(x) = 0\\h(x) = |x|\\f(x) = \begin{cases}1& x< 0\\0 & x \ge 0\end{cases}$$
$g \le f \le h$ on the closed interval $[0,1]$ and $g(0) = f(0) = h(0)$, but $g$ and $h$ are continuous at $0$ while $f$ is not.

That said, if the *domain* of $f$ lies entirely on one side of $a$, Then it is sufficient that the interval (which must contain $a$) be half-open, or even closed provided it isn't $[a,a]$ for the result to follow. This is because continuity is defined in terms of the domain.